# Control python program with django

Tags: python, django, audio

Hej,
I have written a little music player like winamp in python. It has a GUI (Songname, Play/Pause, Next, Previous, time progress bar), I can open a folder and the audio files are played one after the other.

Now I really like to add a remote control through a webserver hosted on the same machine. My idea is to have the same buttons and outputs (also a time progress bar) as in the GUI on a webpage.

Scenario: I start my music player on my computer (it also automatically starts a webserver), I choose my folder with songs and skip two songs by clicking on the GUI on my desktop. Now I decide to sit on the couch and read a book. After a while the music annoys me and I want to pause it. I grab my phone, visit the webpage and tap on the pause button. The music stops and also the desktop GUI reacts (stops the time progress bar and displays the play button instead of the pause button).

I know how to create a django server and how to run it, but I do not know how to let the django views communicate with my music player on my desktop.

I have googled and read some stuff but I have no idea which way to go:

- signals: don't know if this makes any sense since the two processes are totally detached
- communicate over a database, save the state of the music player in a database row and let both processes update the entry whenever a button is pressed: don't like this idea because I'd like the two processes to commuicate without interpreter
- maybe use UDP/TCP: but why, the processes are on the same machine

If I had to program it right now, I'd choose the database approach or is there any other solution I haven't stumbled upon yet? Shall I use flask instead of django?

If this is a common question and task, I am sorry for repeating, but I just could not find anything stating how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is IPC (inter process communication). My instinct would be to have the music player open a socket, bind to a port, and to listen for commands.

Then in the Django view you open a socket connection to the player, send the command and return a response to the browser.

I you want full two way communication to the browser then you would need to also have a process waiting for output from the music player and sending it back to the browser via a web socket connection. The [standard socket tutorial is very handy](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html).